# Can you re-use parchment paper when baking batches of cookies?

Tags: baking, cookies, budget-cooking

I just finished making cookies. The dough was enough to make multiple batches. I only have one baking sheet. Every time a batch was ready, I used new parchment paper on the baking sheet. Is this necessary or could I just re-use the same piece of paper till all my cookies are baked?

Comment: Invest in the product silpat. Works wonders.

Comment: @Linda Silicone baking mats are indeed great, though as Joe said, they do also insulate the bottom of the cookies and reduce browning and even sometimes change baking time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can reuse parchment paper several times for your cookies (it also works for other dry dishes), depending on cooking time and temperature, with no problem. Change the paper when it gets dirty, dark and/or brittle as it may crumble beyond this point. I always do so with no difference in the results, saving both on money and waste.

Comment: Additionally- you can use two sheets of parchment with one pan. Scoop dough onto one while the other is baking and then switch.

Comment: When I bake multiple batches (I just got out of my 100-cookies-at-a-crack phase) I keep the same sheet of parchment paper on the sheet, remove the cooled cookies from it, throw more dough on the  sheet and pop the tray back in the oven. I haven't noticed any issues with that system.

Comment: @Sobachatina Cookie recipes often depend on the cookie sheet being cold when you put the cookies on. So you need to let the pan cool.

Comment: @derobert Very true, but I've made many a batch of choc. chip oatmeal cookies with hot pans, and usually decreasing cooking time 1-2 minutes is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Please do reuse the baking paper. It is non-biodegradable and non-recyclable because of the silicone so if you MUST use it, make it go several rounds for the sake of the environment.  We always used to use butter paper (before it came in plastic containers) or plain unwaxed paper lunch wrap, greased if necessary.  But for cookies, a greased tray works as well as baking paper, and buttering and flouring a tin does well for cakes. My mother lined her Christmas cake tin with several layers of greaseproof paper on the bottom and up the sides. And don’t forget that waxed lunch wrap is great for cheese, sandwiches and the top of jam jars. Jenny

Comment: .
Re:...”greased tray works as well as baking paper... maybe as a method for reducing attachment of cookies, but cookies with butter in the dough will spread more on a greased sheet pan. Less so with paper which provides more friction.